# Google-plus login

Tags: android, google-plus

I need  google plus login through my app,I got login for all versions except Lolly pop. What is the procedure for google plus login through my app...?
please give me reply what is the actual procedure...

here is my code I have done so far...

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.SyncStateContract;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.OptionalPendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;


public class GmailSignin extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{
    TextView signInButton;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();


    signInButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            signIn();
        }
    });
}


 void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}

private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    Log.d("Signin", "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        Conatants.name=acct.getDisplayName();
        Conatants.email=acct.getEmail();
        Conatants.id=acct.getId();
        Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Details.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    } else {
        // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
    }
}


@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
public void onStart(){
    OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);

    if (opr.isDone()) {
        // If the user's cached credentials are valid, the OptionalPendingResult will be "done"
        // and the GoogleSignInResult will be available instantly.
        Log.d("gmailsignup", "Got cached sign-in");
        GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
        handleSignInResult(result);
    } else {
        // If the user has not previously signed in on this device or the sign-in has expired,
        // this asynchronous branch will attempt to sign in the user silently.  Cross-device
        // single sign-on will occur in this branch.
        opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not ever login with Facebook login google plus , but I 'm pretty used to it  module that helps you. Good luck with [here](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3026)

Comment: The answer should not just include a link. The most relevant parts should at least be copied here.

Answer (score 0):

(I am trying to format the code for like an hour but no luck, someone edit the answer with proper formatting please).

Actual Answer:

This worked for me and it is currently in production so it is tested thoroughly

public class LoginActivity extends FragmentActivity implements View.OnClickListener, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

```
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;     
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

private Button signUpGoogle;

@Override     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    signUpGoogle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_up_google);         signUpGoogle.setOnClickListener(this);

    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)                                 .requestEmail()                                 .build();        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)                            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)                           .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)                           .build();
}

@Override     public void onClick(View v) {         signInGoogle();     }

private void signInGoogle() {         Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);         startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);     }

@Override     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {         super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  //     Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);         if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {             GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);             handleSignInResultGoogle(result);         }     }      private void handleSignInResultGoogle(GoogleSignInResult result) {         AlertsAndLogs.log(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());         if (result.isSuccess()) {             GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();             if (acct != null) {                 //Get details from account: acc and do something when them             }         } else {             AlertsAndLogs.toast("SignUp with Google failed " + result.toString());         }     }

@Override     public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {         AlertsAndLogs.logError(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);     }
```

}

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a modified version of what I use in my app to sign in with Google plus. Works for all api versions I support (14 and up).

In short this class does the following.

- Sets up the `GoogleApiClient` with required scopes when the `Activity` is created.
- Registers an `onClickListener` for the sign in button.
- Starts an sign in `Activtiy` with result when the button is clicked.
- Handles the result of the sign in, in `onActivityResult`.

---

**SignInActivity.java**

```
    public class SignInActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
            GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
            GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
        private static final int SIGN_IN_REQUEST = 101;

        private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);
            initialize();
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
            // Maybe only enable the sign in button as soon as the api is connected
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
            // Check best practices
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
            // Check best practices
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == SIGN_IN_REQUEST) {

                final AppPreference preference = PreferenceFactory.getPreferenceHelper(this);
                GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
                if (result != null && result.isSuccess()) {
                    // DO SOMETHING ON SUCCESS
                } else {
                    // HANDLE FAILED LOGIN
                }
            }
        }

        protected void signInClicked() {

            //SHOW A PROGRESS BAR OR SOME INDICATION OF SIGN IN
            Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, SIGN_IN_REQUEST);
        }

        private void initialize() {

            setupGoogleApiClient();
            setupToolbar();
            setupSignInButton();
        }

        private Toolbar setupToolbar() {

            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            if (actionBar != null) {
                actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                actionBar.setTitle(getString(R.string.sign_in_activity));
            }

            return toolbar;
        }

        private void setupSignInButton() {

            findViewById(R.id.signInButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    signInClicked();
                }
            });
        }

        private void setupGoogleApiClient() {

            GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestProfile()
                    .requestEmail()
                    .requestScopes(Drive.SCOPE_FILE, Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
                    .build();

            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                    .addApi(Plus.API)
                    .addApi(Drive.API)
                    .build();

            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
```

For more info on this have a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating) tutorial on sign in for `Android`.

Answer (score 0):

Google Plus login is going to be deprecated soon, so no worries about that any more

> Beginning March 7, 2019, all OAuth token requests with scopes starting with "plus." (i.e. "plus.me", "plus.login", "plus.profile.emails.read", etc) will fail upon request, and may start to intermittently fail as early as February 15, 2019.

https://developers.google.com/%2B/api-shutdown